# Determine the value of $b$ in $\frac{dy}{dx} = (bx+3)^3$ given the following information.

Tags: derivatives

Determine the value of $b$ in $\frac{dy}{dx} = (bx+3)^3$ given that the tangent to this curve drawn through the point $(1.5, 160)$ also passes through the point $(1, 52)$

So how can I find $b$?

I found out that the equation of the tangent is $y=216x-164$ But how can this help?

Also what confuses me the most is that the question says "tangent to this curve", how can you have a tangent to a curve? I thought you can only have a tangent to a point and not the curve itself?

Comment: By "this curve" you mean the graph of the solution to that differential equation?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the curve is $y=f(x)$ that satisfies the give DE.

Now, given that at the point $(1.5,160)$, we have the tangent equation as

$$\frac{y - 160}{160-52} = \frac{x-1.5}{1.5-1}$$

$$\implies y = 216x -164$$

Hence,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=1.5} = 216$$

$$\implies (b(1.5)+3)^3 = 216$$

$$\implies b = 2$$

Comment: few minutes too late :D...

Comment: Why did you use $x = 1.5$ and not $x = 1$

Comment: I used $x=1$ and got $b$ = $3$ which is wrong.

Comment: Because the point (1.5, 160) lies on the curve

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are considering a curve $y(x)$ such that $$\frac{dy}{dx} = (bx+3)^3.$$

Given a curve $y(x)$ and a point $(x_1, y_1)$ (i.e. $y(x_1) = y_1$), the tangent to the curve in that point is a straight line

$$t(x) = mx + q,$$

such that:

$$\begin{cases}
t(x_1) = y_1\\
m = \displaystyle\left. \frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=x_1}
\end{cases}.
$$

Now, since you already have find out that $t(x) = 216x - 164,$ the you need to find $b$ such that:

$$m = 216 = \displaystyle\left. \frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=x_1} = (b\cdot 1.5 + 3)^3 \Rightarrow b = 2.$$

Comment: Why did you use $x = 1.5$ and not $x = 1$

Comment: The problem statement says that the curve passes from the point $x = 1.5$...

Comment: The curve passes from $x=1.5$. The tangent passes from $x=1.5$ and $x=1$. But the curve and the tangent are two different objects!